# Now to find the lasted version of Node/Alpine Docker image

Tags: docker, node.js

How do I find the lasted version of Node/Alpine Docker image?

In a `Dockerfile` I borrowed, I have `FROM node:13.12.0-alpine`, but on DockerHub at https://hub.docker.com/_/node, I don't find that version anywhere. And it looks like a different notation scheme.

Should I be able to use whatever Node version released, or should I look it up to find out what's available? I would like to know this before I try to deploy in this case, since I can't test it locally.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the image, it is right [there](https://hub.docker.com/layers/node/library/node/13.12.0-alpine3.11/images/sha256-c8b4c2938b54a8a457c601dd5cf10e2890d1f750d24fdafde78df067a9a1a6b8?context=explore).


If you don't specify the version (or rather `a :tag`), the common approach is that the :latest is used implicitly, which (in theory) should correspond to the latest available dockerized version of the software you are running. Thus this leaves you with options to either use the latest or go through available tags and choose the one you need.